# Sending/receiving data in Reactor + Netty based TCP client/server

Tags: java, tcp, java-8, netty, reactor

I have created a simple TCP server/client based on [Reactor library](http://projectreactor.io/). I am using version 2.0.0.RELEASE. There is a documentation on Github about [TCP server](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/wiki/TcpServer) and [TCP client](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/wiki/TcpClient), but it has not been updated for some time and it is not appropriate for version 2.0.0. Now I have build the following example with the help from test cases for [TCP client](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/4b9ef1db68a7d12e6ed54e849108dda446fde1d0/reactor-net/src/test/java/reactor/io/net/tcp/TcpClientTests.java) and [TCP server](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/4b9ef1db68a7d12e6ed54e849108dda446fde1d0/reactor-net/src/test/java/reactor/io/net/tcp/TcpServerTests.java):

```
package com.jernejerin.reactor.samples;

import reactor.Environment;
import reactor.core.DispatcherSupplier;
import reactor.fn.Consumer;
import reactor.fn.tuple.Tuple;
import reactor.fn.tuple.Tuple2;
import reactor.io.codec.json.JsonCodec;
import reactor.io.net.ChannelStream;
import reactor.io.net.NetStreams;
import reactor.io.net.Reconnect;
import reactor.io.net.tcp.TcpClient;
import reactor.io.net.tcp.TcpServer;
import reactor.rx.Stream;
import reactor.rx.Streams;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

/**
 * Created by Jernej Jerin on 9.4.2015.
 */
public class SimpleTcpServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        // environment initialization
        Environment.initialize();

        JsonCodec<A, A> codec = new JsonCodec<A, A>(A.class);

        DispatcherSupplier supplier2 = Environment.newCachedDispatchers(5, "pool2");

        // TCP server
        TcpServer<A, A> server = NetStreams.tcpServer(spec -> spec
            .listen(5000)
            .codec(codec)
            .dispatcher(supplier2.get())
        );

        // consumer for TCP server
        server.log("server").consume(new Consumer<ChannelStream<A, A>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(ChannelStream<A, A> channel) {
                channel.log("channel").consume(new Consumer<A>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(A data) {
                        System.out.printf("Receiving data from client -> %s on thread %s%n", data.getId(), Thread.currentThread());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        server.start().await();

        // TCP client
        TcpClient<A, A> client = NetStreams.tcpClient(
            spec -> spec
                .connect("localhost", 5000)
                .codec(codec)
                .dispatcher(Environment.cachedDispatcher())
        );

        client.open();

        // sample data
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            A a = new A(i);
            client.log("client").consume(ch -> ch.sink(Streams.just(a)));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}

class A {
    private int id;

    A() {}
    A(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

When I run this example I can see from log that server receives only the first example data, while the consecutive example data never reaches the server. What I have managed to find from the log is, that when successfully receiving data, onNext is called on the server and client. This call is therefore missing on all consecutive examples except for the first one. Here is the output from the beginning of the log:

```
12:27:36.632 [main] INFO  server - subscribe: ConsumerAction-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:1024, max-capacity=infinite}}{pending=0}
12:27:36.640 [main] INFO  server - onSubscribe: {push}
12:27:36.641 [pool2-1] INFO  server - request: 9223372036854775807
12:27:37.287 [reactor-tcp-select-2] INFO  r.i.n.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpServer - BIND /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:5000
12:27:37.317 [main] INFO  client - subscribe: ConsumerAction-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:2048, max-capacity=infinite}}{pending=0}
12:27:37.318 [main] INFO  client - onSubscribe: {push}
12:27:37.318 [dispatcherGroup-8] INFO  client - request: 9223372036854775807
12:27:37.325 [reactor-tcp-io-4] INFO  server - onNext: reactor.io.net.impl.netty.NettyChannelStream {channel=[id: 0xef22e0e5, /127.0.0.1:53966 => /127.0.0.1:5000]}
12:27:37.327 [reactor-tcp-io-9] INFO  client - onNext: reactor.io.net.impl.netty.NettyChannelStream {channel=[id: 0xc383ec50, /127.0.0.1:53966 => localhost/127.0.0.1:5000]}
12:27:37.327 [reactor-tcp-io-4] INFO  channel - subscribe: ConsumerAction-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:1024, max-capacity=infinite}}{pending=0}
12:27:37.327 [reactor-tcp-io-4] INFO  channel - onSubscribe: {push}
12:27:37.327 [pool2-1] INFO  channel - request: 9223372036854775807
12:27:37.498 [pool2-1] INFO  channel - onNext: com.jernejerin.reactor.samples.A@3a3cf35
Receiving data from client -> 0 on thread Thread[pool2-1,5,main]
12:27:39.319 [main] INFO  client - subscribe: ConsumerAction-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:2048, max-capacity=infinite}}{pending=0}
12:27:39.319 [main] INFO  client - onSubscribe: {push}
12:27:39.319 [dispatcherGroup-8] INFO  client - request: 9223372036854775807
12:27:39.320 [pool2-1] INFO  channel - complete: Broadcaster-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:1023, max-capacity=1020}{push}}
12:27:39.320 [pool2-1] INFO  channel - cancel: Broadcaster-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:1023, max-capacity=1020}{push}}
12:27:41.320 [main] INFO  client - subscribe: ConsumerAction-{{dispatcher=RingBuffer:2048, max-capacity=infinite}}{pending=0}
12:27:41.320 [main] INFO  client - onSubscribe: {push}
12:27:41.320 [dispatcherGroup-8] INFO  client - request: 9223372036854775807
```

---

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause of this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.